# Using multiple and operator in sql

Tags: sql

I am fully aware that I could use IN function so that I could omit using multiple `or` operator. As it was stated below:

> The SQL IN Condition is used to help reduce the need for multiple OR Conditions 
>   in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

Also, it allows me to use OR operator in a select statement like in the code below:

```
SELECT Code FROM KeyDetails WHERE CodeKey 
IN (SELECT Keyword FROM @ValueTableAnd)
```

But what I need right now is to use it with `and` operator. I know this is not possible with `IN`, but what other options could I use with this scenario?

So for example, I have keywords 1108 and 1109. I wanted to get all codes from keydetails where codekey is 1108 and 1109. I am currently thinking if there would be easier way to get these results without using join.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here by using AND.

Comment: What do you need to use with `and`?

Comment: Not only it is not possible with an `IN` operator, but it also does not make sense, for a simple reason that a single value cannot be equal to more than one value at the same time. Because of that, a condition with an `AND` features not only different values, but also different operators. That is why the right way to go about it is to keep your `AND` statements in place.

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight for clearing my doubts on my unclear idea. I was enlightened. Also, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right.  You can do this with a `join`.  Here is one way:

```
select kd.code
from KeyDetails kd join
     @ValueTableAnd vta
     on kd.CodeKey = vta.keyword
group by kd.code
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @ValueTableAnd);
```

This joins the two tables together on the key word.  It then counts the number of matches.  If the number of matches equals the number of keywords in the table, then all are accounted for and `kd.code` "passes".  Note that this assumes that the values in `@ValueTableAnd` are unique.

If you wanted *exactly* the set of keywords to match, so there are no extras, then the code would have a slight modification:

```
select kd.code
from KeyDetails kd left outer join
     @ValueTableAnd vta
     on kd.CodeKey = vta.keyword
group by kd.code
having count(*) = count(vta.keyword) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from @ValueTableAnd);
```

The first condition is saying "all the keywords match" and the second is saying "there are no extras".

Comment: Wow! This solves my question. But, I just don't understand what do you mean by there are no extras.

Comment: @jellyfication . . . If you ware looking for 1108 and 1109, would it match a code that has 1107, 1108, and 1109?  The "1107" is an "extra".

Comment: Now, i get it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use multiple expressions, connected with `and`, then just use multiple expressions, connected with `and`.

```
SELECT Code 
FROM KeyDetails 
WHERE CodeKey > 'aaa'
  AND CodeKey < 'amt';
```

You can refer to multiple columns with `and`.

```
SELECT Code 
FROM KeyDetails 
WHERE CodeKey > 'aaa'
  AND CodeKey < 'amt'
  AND Code BETWEEN 30 and 50;
```

> So for example, I have keywords 1108 and 1109. I wanted to get all
>   codes from keydetails where codekey is 1108 and 1109. I am currently
>   thinking if there would be easier way to get these results without
>   using join.

You want `or`, not `and`.

```
...
WHERE CodeKey = 1108
   OR CodeKey = 1109;
```